# Missing reference to RegisterHotKey

Tags: c#, winforms, registerhotkey

I can't find on google what reference I must use to be able to use RegisterHotKey. What is it?

And while on the topic, should I use RegisterHotKey if I am trying to create an application which listen for key combination in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `DllImport`, not just a reference. You can find tons more information [at pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html).

In short, if you add:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
```

somewhere in your program, the only remaining tricky part is coming up with the `hWnd` to register to handle the key. The sample code linked at pinvoke.net above should help you use the `DllImport`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you will need to use the RegisterHotKey function from C#:

```
/// <summary> The RegisterHotKey function defines a system-wide hot key </summary>
/// <param name="hwnd">Handle to the window that will receive WM_HOTKEY messages generated by the hot key.</param>
/// <param name="id">Specifies the identifier of the hot key.</param>
/// <param name="fsModifiers">Specifies keys that must be pressed in combination with the key specified by the 'vk' parameter in order to generate the WM_HOTKEY message.</param>
/// <param name="vk">Specifies the virtual-key code of the hot key</param>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if the function succeeds, otherwise <c>false</c></returns>
/// <seealso cref="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx"/>
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
```